# Scroll to the latest inserted row in UITableView using Realm Objects

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I have the following code which is working fine, it gets a list of items from a list in `Realm` called `groceryList` and displays them on a `UITableView` in descending order based on the productName. What I would like to be able to do is scroll to the latest inserted row/item in the table, right now when a new item is inserted the user may not see it since the items are alphabetically reordered and the latest item may not be visible on the tableView.

How can I scroll to the latest inserted row/item in a UITableView?

**Realm Objects:**

```
    class Item:Object{
        @objc dynamic var productName:String = ""
        @objc dynamic var isItemActive = true
        @objc dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
    }

    class ItemList: Object {
        @objc dynamic var listName = ""
        @objc dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
        let items = List<Item>()
    }
```

**UITableView:**

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

        var allItems : Results<Item>!
        var groceryList : ItemList!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            groceryList = realm.objects(ItemList.self).filter("listName = %@", "groceryList").first              
            updateResultsList()
        }

        func updateResultsList(){
            if let list = groceryList{
                allItems  = activeList.items.sorted(byKeyPath: "productName", ascending: false)
            }
        }

        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return allItems.count
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {       
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reusableCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell       
            let data = allItems[indexPath.row]      
            cell.displayProductName.text = data.productName
            return cell
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Let me repeat this back as I don't think this has anything to do with Realm. You have a sorted list of grocery items. When the user adds an item to the list, the list will sort and then you want to scroll to that item. If that's the case, then add the item, sort the list, get the new index of that item (`myArray.index(where: { $0.productName == "the product"})`) and scroll to it [scrollToRow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614997-scrolltorow). Although searching by an item_id would be better, so I would suggest adding that to your Item object.

Comment: Even though the solution from `Dávid Pásztor` worked great, I tried to implement your suggestion just to try it without using notifications, but I'm lost, I only have a little experience with databases in general so I don't fully understand how would you keep track of the last inserted item either by name or by id. I need to learn more about how primary keys work in Realm, I'm just lost as to how would you keep track of the item_id of the last inserted item. Thanks.

Comment: See the Realm Guide on [Primary Keys](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys). Once a primary key is added to the Item, you can always find it by that key. When it's added to the List, it will be the last object; sort the list by product name and find it by that primary key, which will get's its new row index. Then, scrollToRow of that index. Using @DávidPásztor technique of leveraging the observer to fire events that will update your tableview is on point. The addition of adding a primary key will help with the scrolling aspect to the latest added item and guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: @Jay - There are a few things that I don't fully understand about primary keys yet, for instance, once you implement a primary key in your model, do you need to manually assign the key at the item creation or Realm will auto-assign a random number? And again, I'm a little confused on how to keep track of the ID that corresponds to the last entered? Sorry about the silly questions.

Comment: It's something you assign. In some cases it may be a sequential integer. In other cases you just need a unique string, so for example, I use `@objc dynamic var item_id = NSUUID().uuidString`. The ID is assigned as soon as the object is created so you could for example, create the object, get it's uuid, add it to the list, and then scroll to it via that uid.

Comment: I see it's starting to make sense. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Realm` notifications to know when the data source `Results` has been modified, then update your table view from there and do the scrolling as well.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var allItems: Results<Item>!
    var groceryList: ItemList!

    var notificationToken: NotificationToken? = nil

    deinit {
        notificationToken?.invalidate()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        groceryList = realm.objects(ItemList.self).filter("listName = %@", "groceryList").first
        updateResultsList()
        observeGroceryList
    }

    func updateResultsList(){
        if let list = groceryList {
            allItems  = activeList.items.sorted(byKeyPath: "productName", ascending: false)
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return allItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reusableCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        let data = allItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.displayProductName.text = data.productName
        return cell
    }

    func observeGroceryList() {
        notificationToken = allItems.observe { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
            switch changes {
            case .initial:
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
                // Query results have changed, so apply them to the UITableView
                self?.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self?.tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                                     with: .automatic)
                self?.tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}),
                                     with: .automatic)
                self?.tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                                     with: .automatic)
                self?.tableView.endUpdates()
                if let lastInsertedRow = insertions.last {
                    self?.tableView.scrollToRow(at: insertions.last, at: .none, animated: true)
                }
            case .error(let error):
                // An error occurred while opening the Realm file on the background worker thread
                print("\(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @-Dávid Pásztor Sorry but I cannot make this work, function `observeGroceryList ` never gets called. Am I supposed to call it manually? When I insert a new item I'm not reloading the table on purpose to test the Realm notification but nothing gets triggered, so the inserted item doesn't show until I rerun the app. What I did is basically copied and pasted your code and just replaced `tableView` with `myOwnTableView`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @fs_tigre Yes, you need to manually call it, since that's just a wrapper function I created to set up the Realm observer. I forgot to add a call to it to `viewDidLoad`, check my updated answer.

Comment: Wow, notifications in Realm are awesome! - It worked, the only thing I had to do is create an IndexPath and passed it to the `scrollToRow()` method since `insertions.last` is just an integer and `scrollToRow` requires an IndexPath as the first parameter. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @fs_tigre This is a great answer. The only 'gotcha' is if an object is *modified* instead of added (inserted), this code wont scroll to the new name. So for example if the name is modified and realm is updated thusly `realm.add(theItem, update: true)`, insertions will be nil so the table will not scroll to the new name.

Comment: Got it, in my case that is not a problem since the editing is done directly on the row. Thanks.

Comment: beginUpdates and endUpdates is deprecated, we should use performBatchUpdates instead.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code as extension of tableview.

```
extension UITableView {
    func scrollToBottom() {
        let sections = numberOfSections-1
        if sections >= 0 {
            let rows = numberOfRows(inSection: sections)-1
            if rows >= 0 {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rows, section: sections)
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    self?.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now simply use it in your method:

```
func updateResultsList(){
       if let list = groceryList{
             allItems  = activeList.items.sorted(byKeyPath: "productName", ascending: false
             yourTableView.scrollToBottom()
      }
 }
```

Just use this method where you want, it should be scroll down.

```
yourTableView.scrollToBottom()
```

Comment: @-MRizwan33 Isn't this always scrolling to the bottom of the table? I need to scroll to the latest inserted row. Sorry I'm not in-front of my computer at the moment to test it.

Comment: it will always to bottom of screen if you call it just after item added. and i have tested it. It is working fine.

Comment: I need, it to scroll to the last inserted row, not to the bottom. Thanks.

Comment: you mean last inserted row can be in the middle of tableview? Then no this will work only going to the bottom of screen.

Comment: Yes, it could be anywhere, middle, top or button etc.

Comment: then this logic will be change to first find the index of last inserted item then scroll tableview to that index. this can be achieve by changing logic of given method above.

Comment: Well, that's the part I don't fully understand.